# WebClient server faces 503 error when accessed on LAN

Tags: c#, port, webclient, http-status-code-503

So I've recently copied the codes from https://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server
to learn about how to host a server from a C# winform. The issue is, even though the example code worked perfectly fine when I accessed localhost from my local computer, when I attempted to connect to the same server using the url http://192.168.x.x:8080/test/ from another wifi-connected computer I get error 503 : Service Unavailable.

All the similar questions I found so far on stackoverflow concerns the use of IIS. I haven't used such services, merely utilizing ASP.Net and nothing else. Previously, I had the error 504 (Bad Hostname) but that was resolved through cmd command (netsh http add url ...) , and I've also opened the port by modifying the Inbound Rule to allow connection through port 8080. However, this 503 error doesn't seem to go away...

Looking forward to any kind of help

Comment: What are the prefixes you pass to WebServer constructor? Can you please share the source code?

Comment: Works for me (from another PC on the same wireless network): `WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://localhost/test/", "http://172.20.10.3/test/");`

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize I had to provide an extra "http://192.168.x.x/test/" on my prefixes too to make it work. Thanks so much!